# Get Admin email using WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there an REST endpoint that can provide the admin email on the WooCommerce installation. I have gone through the documentation for the REST API here https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs and I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

GET /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/1 seems to work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).